# Using the show method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make the button reveal my paragraph after it is clicked. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

```
function $() {
    "use strict";
}
$(document).ready(function () { "use strict";
    $("button").onClick(function () {
        $("p").show();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Please always post the relevant HTML and CSS with your questions so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Do you know how to import jQuery?

Comment: Why is this question with a simple error in it that doesn't provide all of the relevant code being up voted?

Comment: function $() {
    "use strict";
} <---- ummmmm  and onClick is not jQuery..... so not sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of `onClick()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

You can always check for Javascript errors at the developer tools console (in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) it is available by clicking F12).

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is referenced with `$`. The first function declares a function with the name `$`, thus overwriting the JQuery `$` variable. Since "use strict" only applies to the scope it sits at the top of, and given that your first function has no other code in it, that first function is meaningless and is only causing problems, remove it.

The method you want here is `on`, not `onClick` (`onclick` is a very old way to set up click event handlers via HTML attributes or as a property of a DOM object, but you have a JQuery wrapped set object, which doesn't support that):

```js
$(function () { 
    $("button").on("click", function () {
      $("p").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show the text</button>
<p class="hide">This is a test</p>
```